# Searching for ip addresses using wingrep

Tags: regex

I'm using WinGrep to search for IP Addresses in a .txt file, but i can't figure out how to get it to use a regular expression to search. does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Perhaps you could try Visual Basic? ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to consider IPv6, only want numeric IP addresses without port numbers, and don't need to validate the addresses (i. e., not matching illegal addresses line `321.456.299.999`) then you can use

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

If you need to do any of the above things, please update your question.

Comment: The + is not needed after \d as you specify {1,3}

Comment: Erm, yes. No idea how they got there :)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me using WinGrep is the following:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

I tried more sofisticated regex'es but none of them work with WinGrep

Hope it helps
Regards