# How to extract the ip address from the captured packet in java in windows?

Tags: java, networking, winpcap, jpcap

I am working on Network Monitoring. I wish to monitor the data and check the network usage details of the client PC from the admin PC.
 I have figured that I can fulfill this with the help of  captured the packets of the browser as shown below. (This is the packet of FB request)

> New packet1459690210:290428 /192.168.0.138->/31.13.79.220 protocol(6) priority(0)  hop(128)  offset(0) ident(2687) TCP 49281 > 443 seq(1708554008) win(258) ack 938747547  P

But, how can I extract the ipaddress of destination from the captured packets.

I wish to store the data in the database and display as below in the image.

I also wish to have data usage in MB. 
Many thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: use a regular expression?

Comment: @Shachi Its a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html), Please have a look

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323295/searching-for-ip-addresses-using-wingrep

Comment: it helped.... thanku :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\d*

This is what I got. This regex retrieves the ip addresses.

I still have to figure out how to get the used MBs. If any one can help, I shall be greatful